# How to obtain PowerPoint File Format Programmatically

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I need to determine whether the `ActivePresentation` is 97-2003 or 2007 format. I really won't want to check the extension.

Is there a property somewhere inside the PowerPoint Object Model which gives this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no File Format property, unfortunately. You'll have to go the extention route, like:

```
Sub APFileFormat()
Dim ap As Presentation
Set ap = ActivePresentation
Length = Len(ap.Name)
Match = InStrRev(StringCheck:=ap.Name, StringMatch:=".")
ExtentionLength = Length - Match
    Select Case ExtentionLength
        Case 4
            FileFormat = "PowerPoint 2007-2010"
        Case 3
            FileFormat = "PowerPoint 97-2003"
        Case Else
            FileFormat = "undetermined"
    End Select
Debug.Print "The file format of the active presentation is " & FileFormat
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

When the presentation is open there is no file format, its all in memory. However the file it came from can be in either the older [binary format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313106(v=office.12).aspx) or the newer [OpenXML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd926741(v=office.12).aspx). The easiest way to tell the difference is to look at the first few bytes of the file.

For the binary formats it is an [OLE Compound File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942138.aspx) which will always start with the bytes:  0xD0, 0xCF, 0x11, 0xE0, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0x1A, 0xE1.

For the newer formats it is a [ZIP file](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) which will always start with the bytes: 0x50, 0x4B, 0x03, 0x04

Looking at the first few bytes of the file is the best way to quickly determine the file type, though it takes more work.

Comment: I found this answer a lot more useful than the other one.