# Detect PowerPoint version

Tags: vba, ms-office, file-format, powerpoint

Is it possible to detect the version of a powerpoint(PowerPointXP etc) file?

Comment: Are you looking for the file-format version, or the version of the program used to write the file? For example, Powerpoint 2007 can save Powerpoint 2004 files; do you need to know that the file uses the 2004 format, or do you need to know that the file was saved by PP 2007?

Comment: You will want to see this link,it is helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916154/how-to-obtain-powerpoint-file-format-programmatically?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the version of the PowerPoint application being used:

```
Sub getVersion()
    Debug.Print Application.Version
End Sub
```

To detect the version of the PowerPoint file format:

Use [DSOfile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351)